# for loop keeps timing out, but it looks fine

Tags: php, for-loop

Morning, I have a script tha is calling entries from a database, their history actually, and then displays the entries in a table, right now in order to create the table im using a pretty big for loop to make comparisons and add the results in. However for some reason it is timing out after the 30 seconds(the loop doesnt make that many cycles) i have dtermined that the cause is an issue with the first inner loop due to the fact that the echo statement in there just repeats for the duration of the loop, it never leaves that. any ideas?

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $FirstCount; $i++)
    {

    $HistoryTable .= "<tr>";
        if($i = 1)
        {
            for($j = 0; $j < $ThirdCount; $j++)
            {
                if($EntryTwo[0][$j+1] == $EntryOne[$j])
                {
                    $HistoryTable .= "<td></td>";
                }       
                else
                {
                    $HistoryTable .= "<td>".$EntryTwo[0][$j+1]."</td>";
                }
            echo    $EntryTwo[0][$j+1].' == '.$EntryOne[$j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $first = 0;
            $second = 1;
            for($k = 1; $k <= $SecondCount; $k++)
            { 
                if($EntryTwo[$first][$k] == $EntryTwo[$second][$k])
                {
                    $HistoryTable .= "<td>".$EntryTwo[$second][$k]."</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $HistoryTable .= "<td></td>";
                }
            $first++;
            $second++;
            }
        unset($k);
        unset($first);
        unset($second); 
        }
    $HistoryTable .= "</tr>";
    }
```

variables:

```
$FirstCount = 4;
$SecondCount = 18
$ThirdCount = 17
```

Comment: there variable amounts are at the bottom of the code snippet, their obviously called before hand though, ill go ahead and move them up

Comment: Hi, it is at night here :)

Comment: @Antony 1041 am here and snow everywhere :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if($i = 1)` is setting `$i` to 1 every time, so it's an infinite loop.

What you want is `if ($i == 1)`.

Comment: A second set of eyes never hurts, especially on those silly little pieces that just get glossed over.